# Why do I get a null pointer in this TestNG DataProvider annotation method?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, testng

I am having a problem with this TestNG DataProvider method.  Can anyone tell me why this error occurs and help me fix this class?  I am having trouble inserting into the array.

The error I get is vague :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tr.test.TestScript.createData(TestScript.java:55)
```

And here is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
@DataProvider(name = "addresses")
public Object[][] createData() {
    Object[][] objs = new Object[100][];
    CSVReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new CSVReader( new FileReader("input.csv"), ',' );
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Object[] nextLine;
    int row = 0;
    try {
        while ( ( nextLine = reader.readNext() ) != null ) {
            System.out.println( "Adding test case " + (row+1) + ": " + nextLine[0] + ", " + nextLine[1] + ", " + nextLine[2] );
            objs[row][0] = nextLine[0]; //this is line #55
            objs[row][1] = nextLine[1];
            objs[row][2] = nextLine[2];
            row++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if ( objs == null ) {
        System.out.println("Error: Input file empty.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return objs;
}
```

Comment: I added a comment in the code to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't initialised `objs`. Personally, I would build an ArrayList and:

```
return list.toArray();
```

Also, the item you need to add to the list needs to be initialised as well:

```
ArrayList<Object[]> = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
...
Object[] foo = new Object[2];
foo[0] = nextLine[0];
foo[1] = nextLine[1];
foo[2] = nextLine[2];
System.out.println( "Adding test case " + (i+1) + ": " + a + ", " + c + ", " + s );
list.add(foo);

...
Object[][] objs = new Object[list.size()][];

for (int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    objs[i] = list.get(i);
}

return objs;
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work.  This is an annotated method and I believe its required to return as a Object[][] .  When I used ArrayList it seemed to choke.

Comment: @djangofan Added additional way of returning an array.